# Braintree Transaction issue

Tags: php, laravel, payment, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using braintree sandbox payment in my laravel project.

The problem is when i create transaction it ends up the vault section rather then transaction section.

```
    $result = \Braintree_Transaction::sale([
             'customerId' => $brainTreeUser->customer->id,
             'amount' => 100,
             'paymentMethodNonce' => $client_nonce->paymentMethodNonce->nonce,
             'options'=>[
                'submitForSettlement'=>true
             ]
        ]);
```

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the Vault section rather than the transaction section? Are you referring to the Braintree Control Panel? Transactions should still show up in the Transaction search. Additionally, with you passing a customer ID, it will likely store the customer in the Vault.

Comment: Yes i am talking about Vault section in BrainTree Control Panel. When i search Transaction, there are no transaction and it does not show in the graph at dashboard. When i search the vault all the transactions are stored there with status of Authorized

Comment: Try adding this to your options: `"storeInVaultOnSuccess" => false`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. @Saad, there may be something going on with your specific account for search. If you're still experiencing issues, I recommend contacting [Braintree's Support Team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).

Comment: Thanks it automatically started working without "storeInVaultOnSuccess" => false